# Can I do reliable send and forget on RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I want to send messages from a client computer to a consumer on a server computer over an unreliable connection. In my program I don't want to worry about the connection, just say "send message" and forget about it, knowing that it will be delivered whenever the connection is availaible.

In ActiveMQ I can acheive this by installing an ActiveMQ broker on client and server and connecting them together. From my program I send the messages to a queue on the ActiveMQ broker on the client computer. The consumer program connects to the ActiveMQ broker on the server computer and ActiveMQ does the rest.

I'm evaluating RabbitMQ and would like to know whether RabbitMQ can do something similar? I don't want to have to manage checking for return messages in case of failed delivery etc. I just want it to take the message and forward/deliver the thing whenever it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do this with RabbitMQ. If you want to use the same model as what you described with ActiveMQ (installing brokers on both your client and server machines) then install the two brokers and connect them using the RabbitMQ [shovel plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html#rabbitmq_shovel). That plugin shunts traffic from broker to broker, and will give you the behavior you're seeking.

Comment: Thanks, good answer to my actual question but one thing has pricked my interest. You said "If you want to use the same model as what you described with ActiveMQ..." - actually no. Ideally I'd prefer to not have to install the broker on the client, just use a client connection library (from Java, incidentally). If there were a way to do that and still have a nice experience like I describe (not having to detect failed sends and manually manage the data on a local queue in my program) that would be fantastic! Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately the RabbitMQ client library doesn't (AFAIK) include local queuing to cater for the remote broker being unavailable at the time of event production. RabbitMQ does however include capabilities like broker clustering and queue replication which would allow you to make your system highly available and tolerant of a single broker's failure. You could always implement local queuing yourself, but then you'd have to severely complicate your client's logic to cater for broker downtime. It's all possible, but it is easier to have an always-running broker do that work for you.